# Is it possible to define an image map area by radial coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am familiar with the online Imagemap Generators for use in HTML pages. They are convenient when you are creating rectangular or circular areas.

However, if your area is pie-shaped, it makes things a little more complicated. For example, if I have this shape and I wanted to make each pie slice a separate area, this is what the image map code looks like when I use an online imagemap generator.

```
<img src="url/to/your/image.jpg" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="Slice1" title="Slice1" href="#" shape="poly" coords="149,2,146,294,40,250,4,172,14,85,73,23" />
    <area alt="Slice2" title="Slice2" href="#" shape="poly" coords="153,1,251,38,286,86,299,148,287,207,244,264,206,283,155,295" />
</map>
```

[image: Pie chart]

This is the downside when you're using rectangular coordinates on a circular shape: it takes more points to define a pie slice than you would need with radial coordinates. For example I could define a pie slice with (center x, center y, radius, angle start, angle end).

Is there a way to define an area with radial coordinates, or is that not possible in HTML?  From what I read `shape="circle"` is only used for genuine circle and not parts of a circle.

I'm prepared to accept an answer of, "No it's just not possible in HTML." If that is the case, is there an alternate means of achieving the same result on an HTML page?

Comment: I'm not really finding anything showing that it is possible to make HTML image maps coordinates have that capability (though I'd enjoy being wrong on that). But something like this would be pretty easy to put together with an SVG, have you considered that?

Comment: Just detect click and figure out where the click was and handle it with JS instead of html. (I know not 508)

Comment: I haven't learned SVG yet. All I've seen so far are the "hello world" examples, but I haven't made the leap of connecting those examples to the type of things I need to do.

Comment: I don't think you could do a half circle directly but a polygon with one straight side and many many mini-sides (approx 1 per couple of degrees) might be possible. On the whole though..SVG would be optimal.

Comment: Is it always going to be half a circle?

Comment: No. That was a simple example. They will be equal-area slices, anywhere from two to eight.

Comment: maybe these few pens of mine (html/css) can give you some hints : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/voacJ http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/tkzoa http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/lBEmA  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/hqmLi

Comment: @GCyrillus -- Very interesting. I hadn't considered this approach.. I'll need to take some time to digest this, but I'm seeing multiple uses.

Comment: You can use [renderer.arc](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.arc) which allows to print shape which you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to use an image map. You can use point.events in the highchart settings to detect the click and redirect the user with window.location. I wrote the code to output to the console onclick instead of redirecting. (Sorry for an elaborate demo, I just picked one of the highchart demos instead of starting from scratch.)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false,
      type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
          style: {
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Brands',
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function() {
            //location.href = this.options.url;
            console.log(this.options.url);
          }
        }
      },
      colorByPoint: true,
      data: [{
        name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
        y: 56.33,
        url: "http://www.example.com/ie"
      }, {
        name: 'Chrome',
        y: 24.03,
        sliced: true,
        selected: true,
        url: "http://www.example.com/chrome"
      }, {
        name: 'Firefox',
        y: 10.38,
        url: "http://www.example.com/firefox"
      }, {
        name: 'Safari',
        y: 4.77,
        url: "http://www.example.com/safari"
      }, {
        name: 'Opera',
        y: 0.91,
        url: "http://www.example.com/opera"
      }, {
        name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
        y: 0.2,
        url: "http://www.example.com/other"
      }]
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: After customization -- such as allowing for multiple pie-slices rather than only one at a time -- this might very well do the job.

Answer (score 0):

a little snippet to define the area as a pie-slice + jquery to convert this into the poly-format

https://jsfiddle.net/vxmok40g/4/

```
<!-- a pie-slice, 
centered at {x:150, y:150} 
with a radius of 150px 
startangle: 0° 
turning 180° clockwise -->
<area alt="Slice1" title="Slice1" href="#right" shape="pie" coords="150,150,150,0,180" />
```